# Setting up Shoryuken, Active Job and Amazon SQS in a Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-sqs, rails-activejob, shoryuken

As a relative newcomer to AWS, it has been a little bit of curve getting Shoryuken gem (with Active Job and Active Record) to work based on the setup documentation.

1. **Middleware**: I wasn't sure if the middleware was a requisite part of setting up since it was only yielding in the basic example. Is my understanding correct that it is useful if you need to perform operations before or after fetching messages from the queue.
2. **Shoryuken inserting but not fetching messages from SQS**:  At this point, Shoryuken is delivering message to the SQS queue, I can see the messages (in messages visible) in the AWS console but Shoryuken is not fetching them to perform even though there is nothing in the queue.

**Console**

```
irb(main):003:0> InvitationMailer.send_invite(ii).deliver_later
    Enqueued ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID: 5c65184c-8656-42bd-95ce-e0ded78a9a44) to Shoryuken(development_mailers) with arguments: "InvitationMailer", "send_invite", "deliver_now", gid://projectname/Invitation/25
    => #<ActionMailer::DeliveryJob:0x007f7fad761a40 @arguments=["InvitationMailer", "send_invite", "deliver_now", #<Invitation id: 25, invite_code: "324234325", sender_id: 7, invitee_first_name: "Kylo", invitee_last_name: "Ren", invitee_email: "test128@somewhere.com", status: "sent", joined_member_id: nil, created_at: "2016-09-24 03:14:44", updated_at: "2016-09-24 04:16:36", invite_message: nil, sent_at: nil, accepted_at: nil, completed_at: nil, clicked_at: nil, source: nil>], @job_id="5c65184c-8656-42bd-95ce-e0ded78a9a44", @queue_name="development_mailers">

irb(main):004:0> Shoryuken.options
=> {:concurrency=>25, :queues=>[], :aws=>{}, :delay=>0, :timeout=>8, :lifecycle_events=>{:startup=>[], :quiet=>[], :shutdown=>[]}}
irb(main):005:0>
```

**Shoryuken.yml**

```
aws:
  access_key_id: <%= ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] %>
  receive_message:
    attribute_names:
    - ApproximateReceiveCount
    - SentTimestamp
  region: <%= ENV['AWS_REGION'] %>
  secret_access_key:  <%= ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] %>
  concurrency: 25
  delay: 0
  queues:
    - development_mailers
```

How can I figure out why the messages are not being retrieved and acted upon by Shoryuken?

(I had posted [this issue to GitHub](https://github.com/phstc/shoryuken/issues/253), but re-posted here after not receiving a response).

Comment: regarding to middleware, could you point me the docs that confused you?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the YAML formatting was incorrect. `queues` should not be under `aws` but at the same level. Here is the correct version:

```
aws:
  access_key_id: <%= ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] %>
  receive_message:
    attribute_names:
    - ApproximateReceiveCount
    - SentTimestamp
  region: <%= ENV['AWS_REGION'] %>
  secret_access_key:  <%= ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] %>
concurrency: 25
delay: 0
queues:
   - development_mailers
```

Comment: Solution reference: https://github.com/phstc/shoryuken/issues/253#issuecomment-251468159